# jackson serialise to json excluding type

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection, jackson

i'm using hibernate to lazily retrieve content from a database. 
This content is then serialised to json output, the problem is that jackson invoke getters on the "persistentBag" i get from hibernate, ending with a "no session or session was closed" exception.

In fact i would like to tell jackson "if a list is not loaded (means if it's a persistentBag) then don't serialise it"

What is the best way to achieve this ? Any jackson config to excluse persistentBag from serialisation ?
Should i use reflect api to set persistentBag to new empty list ?

What's the best ? Thank you and happy new year guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use `@JsonIgnore` to entirely ignore the marked property. Annotation wise I don't think there is a "if lodaded" option.

What you could of course do is to write your own marshaller that checks the type and decides how to proceed.

I have e.g. written a serializer for a custom data type

```
public class PropertyValueSerializer extends JsonSerializer<PROPERTY_VALUE> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(PROPERTY_VALUE property_value, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
                          SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeFieldName(property_value.getKey());
        jsonGenerator.writeString(property_value.getValue());
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Which is then used to serialize that type by adding some annotations:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = PropertyValueSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = PropertyValueDeserializer.class)
public class PROPERTY_VALUE implements Serializable{

    private String key;
    private String value;
```

That custom serializer gives you full control, but is of course a bit more work to implement than just a simple annotation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If i understand well, i have to make my own persistentBag, with the key and value properties. Instead of the hibernate persistentBag i need to get my own for database results (dunno if it's possible without deep hack). Then i can specify how to handle serialize process in my custom marshaller.

Comment: I wonder if using reflection is not easier since i do not know how to make hibernate using my tweaked persistentBag

Comment: No, you would not make your own persistent bag, but rather write a custom serializer for types that have persistent bags in them, so that you can check if they can be accessed and thus serialized or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would first look into [Jackson Hibernate module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-hibernate), since it adds support of a few Hibernate-specific things, such as handling of lazy loading.
It could also be extended to allow disabling of output for not-yet-loaded collections, since it already knows how to lazy-load collections if need be.

Also, in general you can prevent output of empty collections by using

```
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)
```

which will add matching property if and only if it has at least one element.

Comment: This is a good tip to know, but it must somehow invoke Collection.isEmpty. I don't want this since my hibernate session is gone and results in an exception. But still nice to know, thank you

Comment: Ok. Yes, it requires knowledge of emptiness in one form or another, so that may be problematic.